# Make an RGB mask. cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:241: error: (-215) (mtype == 0 || mtype == 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, mask, scikit-image

l did superpixel segmentation where l get 50 different regions.

Now l would like to assign for each region mask a different RGB color.

Since l have 50 segments,  l would like to get 50 different colors as follow  :

```
color_segment=['red','gree,'blue','orange',.....,'magenta'] # 50 different colors
```

1) My code :
This code work by assign only white mask for each region (value 255)

```
def access_pixel_superpixel(image):

    image = cv2.imread(image)
    segments = slic(img_as_float(image), n_segments=50, sigma=5)
    # show the output of SLIC
    fig = plt.figure("Superpixels")
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.imshow(mark_boundaries(img_as_float(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)), segments))
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()
    plt.cla()
    plt.close()
    #p=255
    for (i, segVal) in enumerate(np.unique(segments)):
        # construct a mask for the segment
        print("[x] inspecting segment %d" % (i))
        mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
        #import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
        mask[segments == segVal] = 255



        # show the masked region
        cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)

        cv2.imshow("Applied", cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask))
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

2) Second try :

This code works with a grayscale color mask only. Only one channel varying from 0 to 255.
def access_pixel_superpixel(image):

```
image = cv2.imread(image)
segments = slic(img_as_float(image), n_segments=50, sigma=5)
# show the output of SLIC
fig = plt.figure("Superpixels")
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.imshow(mark_boundaries(img_as_float(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)), segments))
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
plt.cla()
plt.close()
p=255
for (i, segVal) in enumerate(np.unique(segments)):
    # construct a mask for the segment
    print("[x] inspecting segment %d" % (i))
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
    #import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
    mask[segments == segVal] = p
    p -=5



    # show the masked region
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)

    cv2.imshow("Applied", cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

3) what l would like to get but doesn't work
For each mask assign a different RGB color

color_segment=['red','gree,'blue','orange',.....,'magenta'] # 50 different colors

I tried red color [255,0,0] as follow :

def display_mask_segments(image):

```
image = cv2.imread(image)
segments = slic(img_as_float(image), n_segments=50, sigma=5)
# show the output of SLIC
fig = plt.figure("Superpixels")
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.imshow(mark_boundaries(img_as_float(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)), segments))
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
plt.cla()
plt.close()

for (i, segVal) in enumerate(np.unique(segments)):
    # construct a mask for the segment
    print("[x] inspecting segment %d" % (i))
    mask = np.zeros(image.shape[0:2], dtype="uint8")
    #import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
    mask[segments == segVal] = [255,0,0] # red color



    # show the masked region
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)

    cv2.imshow("Applied", cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However l get the following error :

```
 mask[segments == segVal] = [255,0,0]
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 1034 output values where the mask is true
```

4) Change mask shape to RGB  :
l changed my mask to RGB shape so that it can receive RGB values such as 
[255,0,0] as follow :

```
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype="uint8")
mask[segments == segVal] = [255,0,0]
```

However l get the following error at :

```
cv2.imshow("Applied", cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask))
```

which is  :

```
    cv2.imshow("Applied", cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask))
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:241: error: (-215) (mtype == 0 || mtype == 1) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function binary_op
```

5) Visualisation :

l get  :

[resulted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDrlu.png)

What l'm looking for :

[Looking_for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEp4L.png)

**My question is how can l make an RGB mask ?**

Thank you

Comment: You are almost there!  Your mask needs to be shaped `(M, N, 3)`, so try `np.zeros(image.shape[:2] + (,3))` (or, if your image is already color, `np.zeros(image.shape)`.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt, please look at 4) this is what l tried but it doesn't work (yes my image is already color). l get the following error : cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:241: error: (-215) (mtype == 0 || mtype == 1) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function binary_op . Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what OpenCV does in that case.  But if you tried the same operations with NumPy and displayed the result with matplotlib.imshow, I'd be able to help you debug.